# Syncronizing memory represented by ctypes pointers accross python processes on multiple platforms

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, ctypes, python-multiprocessing

I am running two Python 3 interpreters, one on a Linux and one on a Windows system. They communicate (i.e. exchange data) using `multiprocessing.connection` (`Client` and `Listener`). Between the two, I have to keep the contents of arbitrary data structures represented by `ctypes` pointers in sync.

The problem is that I need to ship the contents of the data back and forth efficiently. `multiprocessing.connection` will `pickle` any data shipped, so I must serialize the data into something that can be pickled.

So far, I turn every sequence of bytes in memory into a Python list of Python integers. Well, it (at least) works ...

```
def generate_pointer_from_int_list(int_array):

    return ctypes.pointer((ctypes.c_ubyte * len(int_array))(*int_array))


def overwrite_pointer_with_int_list(ctypes_pointer, int_array):

    (ctypes.c_ubyte * len(int_array)).from_address(ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(ctypes_pointer).value)[:] = int_array[:]


def serialize_pointer_into_int_list(ctypes_pointer, size_bytes):

    return (ctypes.c_ubyte * size_bytes).from_address(ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(ctypes_pointer).value)[:]
```

I am wondering whether there are ways to make this more efficient (in terms of the amount of data which needs to be transferred and in terms of speed, naturally).

One idea I had was to use strings of Python bytes instead of lists of integers, which would reduce the amount of memory required. However, I did not manage to make it work. How could I change the above routines for that?

What other, possibly much better / faster / more memory efficient options do I have?

---

Usage example for `serialize_pointer_into_int_list`:

```
sample_len = 5
sample_p = ctypes.pointer((ctypes.c_double * sample_len)(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0))
sample_int_list = serialize_pointer_into_int_list(sample_p, sample_len * ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_double))
print(sample_int_list)
print(type(sample_int_list))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 240, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 64]
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: Your `serialize_pointer_into_int_list` returns a ctypes array which isn't picklable.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Maybe a c&p issue? It works for me. I added an example to my question illustrating the correct use of `serialize_pointer_into_int_list`.

Comment: I oversaw the `[:]` at the end which converts the ctypes array to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each data part isn't that large (because copying is necessary for the solution) it can be done this way (shown in interactive shell):

```
>>> import pickle
>>> import ctypes
>>> b = (ctypes.c_double * 5)(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)  # Arbitrary data
>>> d = pickle.dumps(bytes(b))
>>> c = pickle.loads(d)
>>> a = (ctypes.c_double * 5).from_buffer_copy(c)
>>> a
<__main__.c_double_Array_5 object at 0x02F6C9E0>
>>> list(a)
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: Running `bytes` on `b` is a really cool idea, thanks. I did not know that this was possible on ctypes objects. What I do not see though is how I can take into account the length of the memory segment if it is not "obvious" like in your example (array of fixed length of known type). My `serialize_pointer` routine intentionally has a `size_bytes` parameter for this purpose (the `bytes` routine does not have such a parameter). After all, I want it to accept just any type of pointer regardless of the type of data it is pointing to.

Comment: @s-m-e The number of bytes in a `bytes` object can be retrieved with the usual `len(c)`.